# Replace a view in splitter window during runtime in mfc vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, view, mfc, pane, csplitterwnd

I would like to know a way to change the view of a particular pane in a splitter window.

It should be something like an explorer window. Where on click of any tree branch on left side of window right hand side view updates.

Similarily i would like to update my view. On click of any tree node a new pane should be displayed at the same position overriding the previous pane.

sample code would be highly appreciated

Comment: See my answer to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255961/how-to-split-a-window-dynamically-in-mfc-without-using-csplitterwndcreate/10258290#10258290

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to replace view or just change what view displays?

By replacing view I mean use different window; for example: replaced CEdit derived view with CFormView derived.

Could you please explain in greater detail what you are trying to accomplish?